# C++ Error on void type parameters

Tags: c++, function, types, void

I've got this header:

```
class jmmvAsync
{
public:
    static void run(LPCTSTR msg);
};
```

and this .cpp

```
void jmmvAsync::run(LPCTSTR msg){
    MessageBox(NULL, msg, NULL, NULL);
}
```

And I'm calling a this function:

```
LPTCSTR file = "file";
thread t(jmmvAsync::run(file), 0);
```

thread function has this structure:

```
thread::thread(void (*aFunction)(void *), void * aArg)
```

Why am I getting wrong types when calling to "thread"?

Error code:
COMPILE : error C2664: 'tthread::thread::thread(void (__cdecl *)(void *),void *)' : cannot make conversion of parameter 1 with type 'void' to 'void (__cdecl *)(void *)'

`thread` function expects paramater 1 to be `void (__cdecl *)(void *)` and my function is just `void`. I don't know how to make my function named `run` the same type as requested.

Comment: Have you tried (`&jmmvAsync::run, file)`?

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing the function, rather than the return value of the function?

Comment: @RefugnicEternium I got this error: '&' needs value L. And "file" is a parameter for `run`, not for `thread`.

Comment: @PaulRooney What do you mean? I'm trying to execute an async task using `thread` function, I need to pass a function to be executed asynchronous, that funcion is void!

Comment: @ProtectedVoid The function you pass to `thread` takes a `void*` parameter. The `void*` it receives when it is called is the second parameter. You're passing the result of calling the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was mentioned in comments (but maybe in an unclear fashion), your code tries to pass the return value of the function, instead of the pointer to the function.

This constructor

```
thread::thread(void (*aFunction)(void *), void * aArg)
```

expects a pointer to a function as the first argument.

This

```
jmmvAsync::run(file)
```

invokes the function and its result is the function's return value (which is `void`). This is absolutely not what you want. You want an address of the function:

```
&jmmvAsync::run
```

Send it to your constructor this way:

```
LPTCSTR file = "file";
thread t(&jmmvAsync::run, file);
```

Note: the second parameter is the `file`, not `0`. This is a common pattern in C: you pass the address of the function and its parameter, which is of type `void*`, and the library code promises to call that function later, passing the parameter to it.

BTW as Aaron McDaid mentions, the type of `jmmvAsync::run` must be exactly what your constructor requests. That is, it must be declared to receive a parameter of type `void*` (not `LPTCSTR`), and be a `static` member function (which it is, judging by your code). Since you are using names like `LPTCSTR`, you probably only want your code to run on Windows, so you don't need to worry about the distinction between `void*` and `LPTCSTR`.

If in doubt, make a wrapper:

```
void wrapper_jmmvAsync_run(void* par)
{
    jmmvAsync::run(static_cast<LPTCSTR>(file));
}

...

LPTCSTR file = "file";
thread t(&wrapper_jmmvAsync_run, file);
```

Comment: But the first argument should be of type `void (__cdecl *)(void *)`. Does `&jmmvAsync::run` have that type? Will it need to be explicitly cast to that type? Or would it be better to write a separate thin wrapper that calls `jmmvAsync::run` on our behalf, and pass the wrapper to the thread instead?

Comment: Thanks, I understood now, Im a noob in C. It compiled successfully. Btw I'm getting a runtime error when executing it. I guess its because the used libs...